# Connecting to PostgreSQL from a Virtual Machine

Tags: postgresql, qliksense, vmware-fusion

I have MacOS Capitain as my OS in which I have Postgres, and I have Windows 8 running on VMWare Fusion, in which I have QlikSence, now QlikSence needs to connect to Postgres through a wizard which I filled like follows:

```
        Host Name: my IP address
        Port: 5432
        database: mydatabse
        Username: myuserName 
        password: myPassword
```

I'm sure that database, username and password are correct, however the connection fails. Any help please, is there any setup or configuration on Postgres?

**Update:** Error msg:

> Error Message :Please check the values for username , host and other
> properties .Description: Access credentials are not valid for this
> connection

Comment: please share the error

Comment: Error Message :Please check the values for username , host and other properties .Description: Access credentials are not valid for this connection

Comment: this must be QlikSence error. please try `psql -h IPADDRESS -U username -d database` to get more info